# Vue3 Electron get user docs folder

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

How can i get the user docs folder path for an electron app running on the desktop.
I've tried the following but get an error that `app is undefined`.

```
import fs from "fs";
const { app } = require("electron");

export function getFilepath() {
  const filepath = app.getPath("userData") + "/settings.json";
  return filepath;
}
```

This code lives in a **helpers.js** file that is being import through my **electron_preload.js** file.

I have no clue what or how to solve this.

```
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from "electron";
const helpers= require("../src/helpers");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("helpers", helpers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're executing the code in your preload environment, it is being run in the renderer process of the corresponding `BrowserWindow`. However, `app` is limited to the main process' execution scope ([source](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app)) which is why your code throws the error.

You will have to expose the path via IPC.

```js
// Main process, app.js or whatever
const { ipcMain, app } = require ("electron");

ipcMain.handle ("get-user-data-path", (event, ...args) => {
    return app.getPath ("userData") + "/settings.json";
});
```

```js
// In helpers.js
import fs from "fs";
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

export async function getFilepath () {
    return await ipcRenderer.invoke ("get-user-data-path");
}
```

For a more in-depth explanation, see the official [Electron IPC tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).

(As a side note: I/O to the filesystem should probably be done by the main process, not the renderer. Worth considering from a security point of view.)